# iPhone:import Video from iphone library

Tags: iphone

i am importing Video from iphone library In my app...but i am unable to do show i studied lots of code on stack over flow but none are working..for me..Basically i am doing sharing on fb and twitter...
..

```
-(IBAction)showVideoLibrary
{
UIImagePickerController *videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
videoPicker.delegate = self;
videoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

videoPicker.mediaTypes =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,nil];    
if(self.popoverController!=nil)
{
    [self.popoverController release];
}
self.popoverController  = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:videoPicker];
popoverController.delegate = self;
popoverController.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:nil animated:YES];

}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it on a real iPhone device.
Here is the code for picking video from iPhone library which i have used in my project.
Just add video method from selector to your desired button.

```
-(void)video
     {
     UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
     [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     imagePicker.delegate = self;
     imagePicker.sourceType = 
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


     imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

     [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];


     }


     -(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info 
     {


     NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

     if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
     == kCFCompareEqualTo) 
     {

     NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

       NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
     // NSLog(@"%@",moviePath);

     if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
     UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
     }
     }


     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

     [picker release];


     }
```

Do not forget to add mobile core services framework and to import

```
 #import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

the string  "moviepath"  give you the path of the video in that iPhone then perform any desired thing with that video
You will get video path after compressing is done  in string  movie path`enter code here`

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];   //  give here the "videourl"  
 [[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  
 [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
 [player play];
```